# Java HttpOnly Flag

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, httponly

I used Servlet 3.0 and I want secure my cookies with HttpOnly flag. my web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

and my Servlet is

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("url", "google.com");
cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60); //1 hour
response.addCookie(cookie);

pw.println("Cookies created");
```

my context.xml is

```
<Context cookies="true" crossContext="true" useHttpOnly="true">
    <SessionCookie httpOnly="true"/>    
</Context>
```

but I can read cookies from Javascript  . Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you using Tomcat? Which version?

Comment: What is your context.xml?

Comment: I am using JBOSS 7, but is it considerable?

Comment: Yes, not all versions of all web servers implement httponly

Comment: As I know Jboss7 support it. i have update my question

Answer (score 3):

The web.xml only configures the session-cookie.

You should add

```
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
```

to your Servlet.